# I lack the necessary rep to create tags - should I suggest the tags here or wait until the tags are 'organically' created?

Tags: discussion, tags

I tried to tag my question as "advice, genre, zombies, post-apocalypse" but my rep is too low to create new tags. The genre zombies and post-apocalyspe do not exist.

edit:
Genre might be too vague maybe genre-specific would make more sense as a tag.

Comment: I retagged your question to add zombies and post-apocalyptic tags.

Comment: thank you @eric

Answer (score 5):

I think suggesting it here is fine as long as you don't mind that sometimes people won't.

I think post-apocalypse is a good tag, genre or genre-specific is probably not,  and I'm split on zombies.

What do other people think?  Going and looking there's not a lot of genre tags - no "horror", no "scifi" or "science-fiction", no "superheroes" or "supers," and a precious few (3) "fantasy."  I think they're probably a good idea though it makes me suspicious that none have been exercised yet!

There is a "lovecraftian" tag already...  Do we go down the chain and make more specific genre tags like "survival-horror"?

This is supposed to be an answer, so I propose:

1. Yes, we create genre tags, but not the tags "genre" and "genre-specific" (they are implied by tagging with a genre)
2. We start with the big ones - scifi, horror, supers, pulp, supers, etc.
3. When people make lower level tags (survival-horror, street-level-supers) that's OK unless it gets crazy, and they should generally incorporate the master tag too.

Comment: I think [genre] is a bad tag, yeah. Lots and lots of stuff is genre.

I prefer [survival-horror] to [zombies] but I don't think there's anything wrong with [zombies].

Comment: Is it possible to create tags other than tagging an existing or new question?